# Is there a programmer orientated alternative to Google Docs?

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, programming, office

I use Google Docs to collaborate with my team. We write notes about how functionality would work, post snippets of code, commands, json etc.

Google Docs has several annoying features (e.g. auto-capitalisation), lacks many features I do care about (e.g. code syntax-highlighting) and extra baggage that I do not need (e.g. fonts).

Is there a more programmer orientated alternative to Google Docs?

Even something simple like a collaborative (GitHub flavoured) Markdown editor would be an improvement.

Comment: notepad++, maybe they have some sort of collaboration plugin

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I would prefer something in the browser.

Comment: Do you need live collaboration, meaning that for instance 3 persons can edit the same paragraph/method/snippet/JSON at the same time? Or is lock-edit-save lock-edit-save collaboration enough?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth taking a look at [EsherPad](http://lesquare.escherpad.com/@yang.ge/A-Collaborative-Real-time-iPython-Jupyter-Client-for-Self-hosted-Jupyter-Servers-tcwtda0jqgbb) which is a project developing a real time collaborative Jupyter notebook system.

As a Jupyter Notebook you can write markdown, code in multiple languages, execute code in the targeted kernel(s), plot graphs, etc., but all in a collaborative framework.  There is a [you-tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=si0QFaDStoo) of it in action that is well worth watching more than once.

At the time of writing this is in private beta.

Answer (score 0):

If you like Gists, try [GistBox](http://www.gistboxapp.com/). There are tons of features and it's searchable! Obviously it's code oriented.

If you like Wikis, try [RedMine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine). It's not as flashy but if you want to add a lot of non-code documentation it might work better.